# How to priorize Zoom meetings on a fritz.box?

Tags: router, latency, qos

is there a way to configure the fritz box to priorize zoom calls?

Of course I could configure the IP to have higher prio, but this is not solving the issue, that I want to have Zoom only to have real time priority and not a stupid windows update which is eating the bandwidth and killing the latency.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Zoom DSCP marking documented at: https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/207368756-QoS-DSCP-Marking

Comment: thank you, did not know this. The things is even if I have the marking, I do not see on fritz box how to configure the priority for the traffic.

Comment: fritz box is running a Linux, from what I recall. If you have ssh access to it, you can use `tc   ... mark ...` to prioritize the traffic. See also: https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/ch21s02.html but you could find other tutorials on the net.